# Is it possible to solve this equation without brute forcing it?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

Right, so I'm trying to keygen this program from crackmes.de
http://crackmes.de/users/lutio/keygenme1_by_lutio/

I'm not asking someone to do this for me, I'm just asking if its possible without brute forcing.

I normally don't have trouble with such things, but for some reason this user doesn't use any variables from the username, only the serial.  He also says that brute forcing isn't allowed to solve his keygen. I believe that it is impossible to solve without brute forcing.

Does someone actually know if its possible to solve without bruteforcing? This is basically the code I have:

```
    unsigned int key = 0x1FE339E4; //compute == this for success

    unsigned int serialvar = unknown; //gennerated according to serial
    unsigned int magic1 = 0x1FE339E7;

    for( int i = 0; i < 0x10; i++ ) {

        serialvar = (((magic1 * i + serialvar) << 0x10) ^ serialvar) + 0x13371337;
        serialvar = (((i * magic1 + serialvar) >> 0x10) ^ serialvar) + 0x73317331;

    }



    unsigned int computed = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < serialvar; i++ ) {
        computed += 0x3C;
    }
```

Right, so at the end of the code, in order to succeed and hit the "goodboy" our unsigned int computed has to be equal to key.

As we know, the "serialvar" is the unknown variable that I have to generate.  (Which I will then generate a serial based off of)

At my level of mathematics and boolean algebra, I believe that this equation is impossible to solve.

Now I'm not exactly sure if this math statement is correct... But if I take key and divide it by 0x3C... I don't get an integer!

Doesn't this sort of mean it is impossible to solve? Since key / 0x3C has no integer solution?

Comment: `key/0x3C has no integer solution`: Well it doesn't need to. If you subtract 0x3C N times, you get at worst an underflow but the value continues. So even though it may look like you can subsitute it by a division, in this case this is not usefull. And BTW: Are you supposed to know the key or is it just for verification?

Comment: The key is used for verification.  I have to find serialvar.  If serialvar == key then I have succeeded.

Comment: Assuming 32 bit ints, there are four solutions to `x * 0x3C == 0x1FE339E4`, namely 0xb3bb40f7, 0xf3bb40f7, 0x33bb40f7 and 0x73bb40f7.

Comment: try to rewrite the problem into mathematic equations instead of code.
don't forget to think in modulo 2^32, if using 32 bit arithmetic...

Comment: Try Maths stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand that correctly, you have the final value of `computed` and you want to know the value of `unknown`...

first of all you have to solve the equation:

computed = serialvar x 0x3C (mod 2^32)

there you may get multiple values of serialvar.

after that you have to reverse the 16 fold loop..

I don't see any simple way how to solve `(((i * magic1 + serialvar) >> 0x10) ^ serialvar)` and the other expression for `serialvar`. 
The top 16 bits of serialvar are not changed because `>>` will make it xor against zeros.
bottom half may be computed by precalculated array. There will probably be multiple solutions (which is very probbable) and your computation will split. 
The same with bottom half will hold for the second expression.

This way the total computation expenses will be similar to bruteforcing.