# Is there a way to get the original value back after this hash function?

Tags: c++

Code:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 0x10; i++ ) {    
   serialvar = (((magic1 * i + serialvar) << 0x10) ^ serialvar) + 0x13371337;
   serialvar = (((i * magic1 + serialvar) >> 0x10) ^ serialvar) + 0x73317331;
}
```

I understand that in order to reverse something, everything must be done in reverse order.  However, I am confused as this is very complicated and it seems like it requires a prior value in order to reverse the current value which would otherwise be impossible to get?  And we're shifting bits, so there is a possibility that values are lost forever.
I.e. if forward is `x + 1` then backwards is `x - 1`.

Now, is it possible to reverse this loop to find the unknown value serialvar if we have the final value of serialvar?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866883/is-it-possible-to-solve-this-equation-without-brute-forcing-it

Comment: Not at all.  Trying to solve this: http://crackmes.de/users/lutio/keygenme1_by_lutio/  Also, this person said no brute forcing was allowed.  So I was confused, as I thought there was possibly an alternative to brute forcing that I was unaware of.  However, now I know.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @DieterLücking Related or repost?

Comment: @remyabel I think related (no repost)

Comment: I actually found a way to solve this without bruteforcing. But why should I post it here if I can just solve the crackme myself? :)

Comment: Actually I looked at that crackme and I don't see how this could help, so I'll try to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the answers here, this is solvable without any bruteforcing.

The loop and addition are easy to reverse. What remains is these 2 xor operations:

```
serialvar ^= (magic1 * i + serialvar) << 0x10;
serialvar ^= (i * magic1 + serialvar) >> 0x10;
```

Let's call the 0x10 low bits the low part and the 0x10 high bits the high part.

In the first operation it's easy to see the low part is unaffected. But it's also the only part that matters in this operation, because the high part gets shifted out. So this operation is actually it's own inverse.

The second operation is a little bit more complicated. This time the high part is unaffected. You almost don't care about the low part except the case when the low parts of the addition `i * magic1 + serialvar` overflow and add 1 to the high part of the sum.

So this operation always takes one of these 2 forms:

```
serialvar ^= (i * magic1 + (serialvar & 0xFFFF0000)) >> 0x10; // no overflow
serialvar ^= (i * magic1 + (serialvar & 0xFFFF0000) + 0x10000) >> 0x10;
```

Now each of these forms doesn't depend on the low part of `serialvar`, so each of them is it's own inverse. So you can simply try both of them and verify which is correct by applying the original operation.

The full code is as follows:

```
serialvar = key;

// compute an inverse
for (int i = 0xF; i >= 0; --i) {
    serialvar -= 0x73317331;

    unsigned int serialvar0 = serialvar ^ ((i * magic1 + (serialvar & 0xFFFF0000)) >> 0x10);
    unsigned int serialvar1 = serialvar ^ ((i * magic1 + (serialvar & 0xFFFF0000) + 0x10000) >> 0x10);

    if (serialvar == (serialvar0 ^ ((i * magic1 + serialvar0) >> 0x10)))
        serialvar = serialvar0;
    else
        serialvar = serialvar1;

    serialvar -= 0x13371337;
    serialvar ^= (magic1 * i + serialvar) << 0x10;
}

cout << hex << serialvar << endl;

// verification
for (int i = 0; i < 0x10; i++) {
    serialvar = (((magic1 * i + serialvar) << 0x10) ^ serialvar) + 0x13371337;
    serialvar = (((i * magic1 + serialvar) >> 0x10) ^ serialvar) + 0x73317331;
}

if (serialvar == key)
    cout << "success" << endl;
```

There's a possibility there could be multiple inverses if both checks succeed, but I didn't look into that as it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  There are only 4 billion values of `serialvar` (assuming the type, which you omit, but is implied by the context).  Many of them may not even be valid serial numbers.  Compute the hash over all of them until you find the one you want.

Answer (score 3):

These types of function are largely one-way functions. The existence on one-way functions seems intuitively impossible, but are in fact very possible. In fact, all modern cryptography relies on such functions. The way that one-way function can exist is because many values map to the same value, for example:

```
1234 -> abc
2345 -> cde
4567 -> abc
```

Ok, so now if you have abc, and are trying to back up, where do you go, 1234 or 4567? By mapping many vaules onto one, you stop people from going backwards. Modern cryptography functions do this millions of times over thousands of steps. The only way to 'reverse' the process is by guessing a starting point and hoping you land at the right end point, and even then you can't be sure you really have the right value.

Your function is a good simple example of this kind of one-way function. You can try to "brute-force" it by guessing, but you can't really just "run the process backwards".

Edit:

After looking at this function more, with the help of @hvd, it looks like this particular function might be reversible if magic1*i doesn't lead to overflow. In that case the code would look like this:

```
for ( int i = 15; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    serialvar -= 0x73317331;
    serialvar = ((i * magic1 + serialvar) >> 0x10) ^ serialvar; //doesn't work... carry
    serialvar -= 0x13371337;
    serialvar = ((magic1 * i + serialvar) << 0x10) ^ serialvar; //reverse by doing again
}
```

This would only work if magic1*i is < 2^15. If you want to account for all possible values of magic1 you would have to follow a small tree that branches once at each of the >> lines, one bit gets clipped. So a 2^16 search area, which is actually quite small.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a one-way function. Do you have any concrete examples of duplicate values for the function in the question? `serialvar = ((serialvar + k) << 16) ^ serialvar;` is easily reversed by repeating the operation. `serialvar = ((serialvar + k) >> 16) ^ serialvar;` is less easy, but seems like it should be possible in a similar way.

Comment: The only part that destroys information is the bitshifts "<<" and ">>". C++ bitshifts do not wrap, so in this case, "<< 0x10" is turning 2^16 different values into one value. This is repeated 32 times. Following that tree would be (2^16)^32 different branches to follow. Far too many. To demonstrate using binary numbers, 0101 << 2 is 0100 and 0001 << 2 is 0100.

Comment: Like I said, `serialvar = ((serialvar + k) << 16) ^ serialvar;` is reversed by repeating the operation. No bits are lost. A loop over all values of a 32-bit unsigned int that verifies that running the operation twice produces the original value takes seconds to complete. It works because it XORs `serialvar` with `((serialvar + k) << 16)`, so only changes the upper 16 bits, but the value of `((serialvar + k) << 16)` only depends on the lower 16 bits.

Comment: Hmm... You might be right. What about overflow when i*magic1 is added? It looks like as long as magic1 < 2^28 or so it might be reversible.

Comment: I'm assuming that the variables are unsigned, so if you take the arithmetic modulo 2**32, there is no overflow to worry about, regardless of the value of `magic1`.

Comment: It doesn't work that easily for the `>>` version, only for `<<`. I'm trying to write up an answer that also addresses `>>` correctly, but no luck so far. :)

Comment: Well I edited my comment, I think you are right. I jumped to conclusions when I saw the bitshifts.

Comment: It doesn't work, but it might with some modifications. This is a nice problem.

Comment: Why aren't << and >> symmetrical? What am I missing?

Comment: It helps if you think of a 32-bit addition as two 16-bit additions, plus a carry. In the `<<` case, the carry is shifted out of the result, but in the `>>` case, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This function is not completely reversible without brute forcing, but you only need to "brute force" a one-bit value. I'll start by expanding the operations slightly.

```
for( int i = 0; i < 0x10; i++ ) {    
  serialvar ^= (magic1 * i + serialvar) << 0x10;
  serialvar += 0x13371337;
  serialvar ^= (magic1 * i + serialvar) >> 0x10;
  serialvar += 0x73317331;
}
```

Obviously, `+=` is reversible by applying `-=` with the same value. The operand is constant, so this is trivial.

Obviously, `^=` is reversible by applying `^=` again with the same value. Here, though, the operand is not constant.

Starting with the first one:

```
serialvar ^= (magic1 * i + serialvar) << 0x10;
```

Because the operand is left-shifted by 16, it will only take the low 16 bits of the expression `magic1 * i + serialvar`, and only toggle the high 16 bits of `serialvar`. That's easy: after this operation, `(magic1 * i + serialvar) << 0x10` still produces the exact same value.

The second one is more complicated:

```
serialvar ^= (magic1 * i + serialvar) >> 0x10;
```

This one only changes the lower 16 bits of `serialvar`, and only the high 16 bits of `magic1 * i + serialvar` are taken, but because addition works with a carry, that still depends on the low 16 bits as well. You'll get `(((magic1 * i) >> 16) + (serialvar >> 16) + carry) & 0xFFFF`, where `carry` may be either 0 or 1.

Now, this part *does* have the potential for data loss. If `magic1 * i` is `534985191`, and `serialvar` is `50712`, the result is `55803`. If `magic1 * i` is `534985191`, and `serialvar` is `50719`, the result is also `55803`. So, there are some values for which you cannot recover the original `serialvar`.

However, since you know `carry` to be either `0` or `1`, you can try both possibilities. If you get a correct result with `0`, and not with `1`, you have your answer. If you get a correct result with `1`, and not with `0`, you have your answer. If you get a correct result with both `0` and `1`, print an error message and exit. Since this is a specially crafted program that's supposed to be reversible, that shouldn't happen.

(Disclaimer: I'm assuming `magic1` and `serialvar` are `unsigned int`, and `unsigned int` has 32 value bits. The program is probably not intended to be portable.)

Comment: Oh well. I didn't see your answer. I guess our approaches are the same, right? (I just don't consider trying 2 possibilities bruteforcing :)

Comment: @user2345215 Yes, that's pretty much the same. I'm a little disappointed that I didn't figure out a simple way to determine whether a specific carry (0 or 1) was possible without completing the calculation both ways, and re-running the original calculation, there should be a much simpler way to determine that.